# Retrieving values from subviews Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have created a subclass of a UIView which is a rotating wheel. This wheel is part of another UIView which has an image in the top right corner. 
When the wheel is turned, in the touchMoved function the right most item is returned (its number). I need to then change the parent's image automatically when the subview is turned (when the number is returned)

Assuming I have this number in the subview, how may I return this to the parent, or change the image (in the parent UIView) from the subview?

Thanks

Comment: To me, it looks as if you have a UIView 'b' inside a UIView 'a' and you want to know how to access 'a' from 'b'. Is this correct? In this case, your question isn't about subclasses but about subviews.

Comment: sounds like you need to use delegate methods. you can call a delegate method from the wheel view which you can set to run in the parent view, which can then pass the value onto the other view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a protocol which defines the method(s) you want to call in your superview:

```
@protocol wheelViewDelegate {
   -(void)doSomething;
}
```

Your superview needs to implement this protocol:

```
@interface superView:UIView<wheelViewDelegate> {
...
}
...
@end
```

Also, you obviously need to implement the `doSomething` method.

The UIView, which contains the wheel needs to be a subclass of UIView and hold the delegate, like this:

```
@interface WheelView : UIView {
id<wheelViewDelegate> delegate;
...
}
@propery (nonatomic, assign) id<wheelViewDelegate> delegate;
...
@end
```

Don't forget to `@synthesize id;` in your implementation.

Now, you can call the `doSomething` in your superview from the subview:

```
[self.delegate doSomething];
```

EDIT:

Okay, I thought this was obvious, but, of course, you need to set the delegate like this:

```
//In your superView:
WheelView* wv = [WheelView initSomeHow];
wv.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Wow thnx this looks good. What I'd like to ask however, how would I know from my superview that the wheel has actually been moved?

Comment: oh wait I understand. So i call the superview when the wheel is in the touchMoved. Thus the implementation of doSomething must be in the superview, right?

Comment: I implemented the above in my code but unfortunately it does not actually enter the method in the superview. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Yes, the implementation of "doSomething" has to be in your superview. For your other problem, please add the relevant part of your code to your questions, otherwise, it's hard to tell what's wrong. PS: I didn't write that you have to "@synthesize id" to make this work but I guess this is rather obvious.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. And please don't open a new question and rather edit the old one. Otherwise, other people will have difficulties when following your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method mentioned by **Phlibbo** is one way to do this. Since your custom view subclass is more like a control with a value, I would subclass `UIControl` instead of `UIView` and use the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event.

In your custom subclass notify the value has changed (maybe in your `touchedEnded:withEvent:`):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Now observe value changes in your controller, and let the controller update the image in the other view.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [wheelControl addTarget:self action:@selector(wheelValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void) wheelValueChanged:(id)sender {
    // update your image based on the wheel value of sender (wheelControl in this case).
}
```

Comment: [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; returns an error

Comment: "returns an error" is not very descriptive. What happens exactly? Any chance you forgot to subclass UIControl?